# How to create (in Flask using flask-SA etc.) an SQLite DB file with metadata.create_all(..)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application spread across modules with blueprints.
Each module/blueprint has its own models.py file where models are defined.

When the application runs, I would like SQLAlchemy to create the SQLite file at the location set with `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` configuration.

With a regular Python application without any extraction layers above SA using `base.metadata.create_all(..)`

How can I do this with Flask and SQLAlchemy extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have somewhere :

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

so all you have to do is

```
db.create_all()
```

Comment: I am trying https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to example of the author. I tried placing `db.create_all()` right after `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` however it is creating a file of sized `zero bytes`.

Comment: You need to do create_all after you import the models which You want to create.

Comment: Quick question: Say I have 2 or more blueprint/modules with their own models.py (as above). If these two models depend on each other and need to import one an other (circular), is it ok to do so? (ex: `cars` might need `users` and `users` might need `cars`)

Comment: I have similar setup (separate apps / blueprints) and no problems with it.